# Mule: Can we remove multiple keys from a map using message property component

Tags: mule

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties" scope="outbound">
    <delete-message-property key="#[payload.remove('5F2A')]"/>
    <delete-message-property key="#[message.outboundProperties.remove('9F37')]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

Please suggest a way in mule where I can remove multiple keys wherein the payload is of Map type

Answer (score 0):

You could use a transformer or component to remove the keys that you want:

Here is an example using a transformer:

```
@Override
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
        throws TransformerException {
    message.removeProperty("5F2A", PropertyScope.OUTBOUND);

}
```

Comment: Hi Alex , The issue is I have to remove multiple keys from the payload which is of Map type. I understand that I can do using a transformer, and that will require code modification. I want to inquire if any predefined transformer can do the task

Comment: As far with my experience working with mule, I have not encountered an easier way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,I will look for other possible ways if any otherwise will write a custom transformer

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are using the enterprise version of the Mule runtime, multiple properties can be removed from a Map payload via DataWeave script within a Message Transformer component, as demonstrated by the following code snippet:

```
...
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
  <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/java"/>
  <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload mapObject {
  ($$): ($)
} - "5F2A" - "9F37"]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
...
```